# How to get unsigned and signed integers in Python using UUID

Tags: python, bit, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I came across a stack overflow question and I saw a way to generate 64 bit integers in Python using the UUID module

```
from uuid import uuid1
uuid1().int >> 64
# expected output “A 64 bit unsigned integer”
```

So this is my question:
How can one generate signed integers (maybe 8bit, 16bit, 32bit, 64bit or 128bit) in place of unsigned integers.

Please forgive my ignorance

Comment: If you simply need random integers, why don't you use [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)?

Comment: `uuid` itself is already just using `random` under the hood to generate the UUIDs in the first place; cut out the middle man.

Comment: I thought so too but uuid gets its unique Id by considering so many dependencies like computer node, time clock and I hear even IP address is part of the list. I just feel that it’s more developed and has more advanced use cases.